# mutate_at to replace NAs with 0

Tags: r, dplyr

```
mtcars1 <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(blah = LETTERS[seq(1,26, length.out = nrow(.))],
         blah2 = letters[seq(1,26, length.out = nrow(.))])

# sprinkle some random NA values
mtcars1$blah[c(1,3,5,10,11)] <- NA
mtcars1$blah2[c(1,2,5,15,20)] <- NA


mtcars1 %>% 
  mutate_at(blah:blah2, function(x) {
    if_else(is.na(x), 0, x)
  })
```

Returns:

```
Error in check_dot_cols(.vars, .cols) : object 'blah' not found
```

How can I replace NAs with 0 across multiple columns using dplyr/tidyverse approach?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can wrap the ranger of column names in `vars` and also make sure that the return `type`s are the same for `if_else` (or `case_when`) based on the documentation of `?if_else`

> Compared to the base ifelse(), this function is more strict. It checks that true and false are the same type. This strictness makes the output type more predictable, and makes it somewhat faster.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars1 %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(blah:blah2),  ~ if_else(is.na(.), '0', .))
```

Here, instead of the anonymous function call (`function(x)`), the tidyverse concise option with `~` is used and as 'blah', 'blah2' are `character` types, the return type for `true` is also quoted (`'0'`)

---

Instead of `if_else`, another option specifically for replacing `NA` is `replace_na` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
mtcars1 %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(blah:blah2),  replace_na, '0')
```